# Apple's Preview app updates (with OS only?)

Tags: macos, preview

I am running Mac OS Big Sur (11) and I don't like the Preview App (bundled app) much.  Since the Preview app's version is 11 and Big Sur is 11, I assume the app is tied to the OS and not capable of being updated without a new OS.   I would assume that with a new OS I would get an updated Preview app - the search function does not use whole strings, just individual words....

Can someone confirm that the more recent OS comes with a new version of the Preview app?

Comment: Mojave is v10.1, Monterey is still 11.0 - doesn't seem like they move in sync.

Comment: Simple yes/no question don't work so well in a Q&A setting. We have a few questions about PDF viewers/alternatives to Preview, maybe you find something there which better suits your needs.

Comment: If you use quote marks around "two words", Preview will search them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Apple bundles Preview, TextEdit, Safari* and other applications with the OS, and each version that comes with each OS is broadly reliant on that OS.

Admittedly, Preview is still on version 11.0 (build 1033.4) in Monterey, though I suspect there are differences nonetheless.

Preview is just a wrapper for various OS functions, like creating a window with a PDF or image in it.

Furthermore, the OS is now on a sealed read-only volume, so you can't really replace the existing bundled apps.

(* It is possible to upgrade Safari independently of the OS.)